# cannot use the mac_alias package to generate an alias

Tags: mac, python, alias

I have about 3000 files and I need to turn them into aliases so doing it by hand is not an option plus in the future I want to be able to do this automatically.  I'm trying to use this package

https://mac-alias.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The module only has three methods, `for_file`, `to_bytes`, `from_bytes`.  I want to be able to generate an alias.  I would think I would need to tell the computer which path I want the alias to occupy and which path I want the alias to point to.  But I only see a method which creates some sort of object using the `for_file` method, but once that is done I cannot figure out what do with it.

In case I'm not being very clear I want to generate an alias which points to a file.

Comment: Why an alias would a symbolic link do?

Comment: Do you know of some python package that does that?

Comment: As to the package how much python do you know?

Comment: i've got about 7000 hours of experience

Comment: Symbolic links are standard python os.symlink

Answer (score 1):

Technically this question was answered by mmmm.  In any case, symlinks do bascially the same things as aliases.  So if you want to create a symlink in python:

```
import os
os.symlink(source, destination)
```

And that should do it.